# sum of n numbers with the power k

Tags: algorithms

I am searching for a good algorithm to solve problem 487 on project-euler. I dont want code or something like that, I only want the name of the algorithm thats best suited. Till now I think of either using Faulhabers Formula or using the stirling numbers of second kind to compute the sum. 
https://projecteuler.net/problem=487
If there is a better algorithm please let me know.

Comment: Computationally it might be easier to work by telescoping $n^{k+1}-1$.